# Flow cannot use a Child Flow because of them being in a different Subscription despite being in same Solution

Tags: power-automate, common-data-service

When I'm saving a Flow which needs to call a child-flow, I'm getting an error to indicate that this flow is in a different subscription.  The error message suggests that I need to move the subscription, however, there is no way to do that within Power Automate.

I'm trying to understand why when:

- Both this flow and the child-flow it is calling are in the same Power Platform environment
- They are both within the same Solution
- Other flows are able to successfully call this same sub-flow

The only thing that I can think of which is different about this flow is that it was created by me doing a SAVE AS on another one in the same solution.  Could that be the problem?

[image]

**Error Message**

```
Request to XRM API failed with error: 'Message: Flow client error returned with status code "BadRequest" and details "{"error":{"code":"InvalidOpenApiFlow","message":"Flow save failed with code 'WorkflowUnderWrongSubscription' and message 'The child workflow '{workflowIdWasHere}' must be under the same subscription as the parent workflow.
```

Any ideas?  Or is there an issue with Power Automate here?

Comment: It seems to be a Power Automate bug.   I just had the same error this morning where I added a parent and child flow to an existing solution in one of our environments.  I have tried multiple other combinations since that time, new solutions, solutions in the default environment that I import to a new environment, etc.  I even created new flows in the same solution successfully.  Most succeeded, with an occasional unexplainable error.  I would suggest you create a new parent flow and try to access the same child flow again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I created the parent flow outside a solution and imported it whereas I created the child flow inside the solution. I solved it by recreating the parent flow inside the solution. No idea why that "fixes" the problem.